# Django/Python error. "ImportError: Import by filename is not supported."

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, importerror

I wanted to install Django and have troubles with the import error.
I read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911085/django-python-environmenterror), but the answer didn't help here. Nothing happend after I changed the env variables to the module path.

```
C:\Users\M>django-admin.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()    
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 302, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

Comment: Show your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable

Comment: 'C:\Python27\django\conf\'

Answer (score 2):

`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` shouldn't be system path to settings file (or directory). It should be an python path to your settings file. So first, make sure that your project is in `PYTHONPATH` or you are inside project directory, then set correct `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and after that, run your `django-admin` command.

You can also clean `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` variable if command that you're trying to issue is not related with existing django project.

Comment: This is my 1st project. If i delete the 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' I still have error saying that I should set this variable anyway OR configure settings, but I dont have idea how.

'error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.).'

Comment: What command you're trying to issue? If this command is not related to project (for example `startproject` command), it should work fine without `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. If this is project related, try using `manage.py` located in your project main directory or set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `yourproject.settings` being in your projects main directory (or having added your project directory into python path)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in windows. Then later I realised that the problem is with the version of Django installed. I am using python 2.7, and it seems that the import by filename is not supported by it. I believe if you use python 3 , there wont be any problem. 
So , I installed django 1.6.5 and the solved the problem.

```
pip install django==1.6.5
```