# I'm getting an error while creating Python Django Project

Tags: django

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>django-admin startproject python_tutorial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 316, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "c:\python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

Can someone please suggest what to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django/Python error. "ImportError: Import by filename is not supported."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481102/django-python-error-importerror-import-by-filename-is-not-supported)

Comment: No idea, just some guesses -- do you use multiple Python versions? Do you have a DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable? Are you using virtualenv or not?

Answer (score 0):

By mistake I have set variable "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" to python path and it messed up. I have deleted this environment variable and it works.