# ImportError: Import by filename is not supported (python 2.7, django 1.9 )

Tags: python, django

```
C:\Users\Sayed>django-admin startproject pp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\arcgis10.3\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\arcgis10.3\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\arcgis10.3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\python27\arcgis10.3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 302, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "c:\python27\arcgis10.3\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "c:\python27\arcgis10.3\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "c:\python27\arcgis10.3\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "c:\python27\arcgis10.3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

i am trying to create a django project, but it's showing an error

Comment: Maybe related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/911085/5509239) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34481102/5509239) .What's the value of `SETTINGS_MODULE`? Is not

Comment: @timgeb The OP seems to be asking how to resolve the `Import by filename is not supported.` error.